# Crear Formulario en el cual al darle a submit, se suba el texto escrito a un server

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un formulario

```
<form action="" method="post" class="basic-grey">
<h1>Bible Form 
    <span>Please fill all the texts in the fields.</span>
</h1>
<label>
    <span>Your Nickname* :</span>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="insert your nickname" />
</label>

<label>
    <span>Your Email* :</span>
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Valid Email Address" />
</label>

<label>
    <span>Message* :</span>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Insert the text u desire"></textarea>
</label> 
 <label>
    <span>Code* :</span>
    <input id="code" type="email" name="email" placeholder="The Code That we sent to your email" />
</label>    
 <label>
    <span>&nbsp;</span> 
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Send" /> 
</label>
```

Mi objetivo es que en ese formulario, al rellenar todos los datos. (Podemos saltarnos el ultimo recuadro del código, eso para después). Y al darle el usuario a submit, se suba lo que hay en MESSAGE a un archivo localizado en el servidor (imagino que eso va por php y mysql). Y a poder ser, que si 10 usuarios suben 10 textos, que todos estos esten en un unico archivo de forma consecutiva (uno debajo de otro).

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de lo que estas pidiendo:

FORMULARIO HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="insertar_colores.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label><br>
                    <input name="nombre" type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="EJ: Un nombre"/>
            </div>
        </div><br>
        <!--FIN CAMPOS-->
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar informacion</button>
</form>
```

INGRESAR DATOS PHP

```
if(addslashes($_POST['nombre']) == '' or addslashes($_POST['nombre']) == NULL){
    echo "Te olvidaste de poner el nombre";
    exit;
}
// APARTIR DE AQUI ES TODO CORRECTO Y EMPEZAMOS A GUARDAR COSAS
        else{echo $razon."<br>";
        #Consulta a la BD para insertar los datos
        $links = conectar_db();
        $consultar_mensaje = "INSERT INTO tabla VALUES ('NULL', '".addslashes($_POST['nombre'])."')";
        $result_mensaje = mysqli_query($links, $consultar_mensaje);
        #FIN conecxion a la BD

//COMPROBACION DE QUE TODO ES CORRECTO EN LA BASE DE DADOS
                    if (isset($result_mensaje) == FALSE) {
                        echo"Error: ".$consultar_mensaje."<br>ERROR TIPO 2".$links->error;
                        echo "<br>No se a enviado el mensaje";
                    } else {
                        echo"Se a guardado en nuestra base de datos<br>";
                        echo"<br><b>Todo correcto</b><br>";
                        }
                    }
}else{echo"Los datos ya han sido introducidos en la base de datos!";}
```

Quiero pensar que ya sabes añadir una base de datos y administrarla para que te llene los campos que tienes que tener creados (solo hice un campo llamado **"nombre"** como ejemplo)

Answer (score 0):

Antes tendrás que manejarte con el envío de datos de formularios html. Tu form no tiene un action. Ahí yo pondría un `executeform.php` por ejemplo. Tampoco veo que cierres la etiqueta html del form `</form>`.

El action del form es el destino. En ese destino tendrá que haber un fichero php en el que recogerás los datos que recibas del formulario (en este caso por método POST) y ya manejarlos a tu antojo... ya sea guardándolos en una bbdd mysql, o bien como indicabas además añadiendo a un fichero los datos de cierto campo del formulario o lo que sea...

Te recomiendo que leas [esto](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Comment: gracias, voy a mirarlo

Answer (score 0):

Realmente lo que tendrás que realizar primero será poner el archivo PHP dónde vas a procesar los datos en el `action` del formulario.

```
<form action="guardoDatos.php" method="post" class="basic-grey">
```

En este ejemplo tomaré como referencia `guardoDatos.php` y la explicación que viene a continuación va a tener referencia solo con este fichero.

Posteriormente, y como estás enviado los datos mediante `post` (method="post"), deberás recuperar los datos, en este caso, mensaje, mediante la variable global `$_POST` en la cual tendrás almacenado cada uno de los campos (`inputs`) que tengan un atributo `name` (después de hacer submit en el formulario).

Por lo tanto, para recuperar el valor de tu mensaje, el cual tiene el atributo `name="message"` lo podrías recuperar mediante `$_POST["message"]`.

Por último, tendrás que realizar la conexión a la base de datos y la inserción de tu mensaje para tenerlo almacenado en tu servidor.

Comment: No he añadido la inserción a base de datos porque entiendo que tu problema está en como utilizar el formulario para enviar los datos al servidor. Sin embargo, si tienes cualquier duda no dudes en preguntar.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo por lo que entendi lo que tu necesitas es utilizar la funcion **fwrite** de php.

Lo unico que tienes que hacer es que ese formulario le envie los parametros a un archivo php que tenga una estructura, algo como esta.

```
if(isset($_POST['message'])){
$data = $_POST['message'];
$carpeta = fopen("archivoUnico.txt", "a+");
fwrite($carpeta, "Mensaje: ".$data."\n");
fclose($carpeta);
```

}

el "\n" para el salto de linea. Y te recomiendo añadir a ese archio el nombre de usuario para saber que usuario mando el mensaje.